# PHP Open URL Delay Target Blank

Tags: php

Please, I need help from an expert in PHP. I have one PHP code that works fine, but I need to add some delay when URL is opened, so now I click and URL automatically instant open in the new tab, I need to add a delay in this code so when I click to open example after 5 seconds. Thanks

```php
<a href="<?php echo clpr_get_coupon_out_url( $post ); ?>" id="coupon-link-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="coupon-code-link" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Click to open site', APP_TD ); ?>" target="_blank" data-clipboard-text="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Show Coupon Code', APP_TD ); ?>" data-tooltip data-click-open="false" data-position="right" data-alignment="center"><span><?php _e( 'Show Coupon Code', APP_TD ); ?></span><i class="fa fa-scissors" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem with Javascript not PHP.

You need to use an onClick event handler on the link and use setTimeout() to wait until the new url can be opened.

Something like this (a sample_file.php):

```
<?php
    $link = "http://www.example.com";
?>

<a href="#" onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.open('<?php echo $link; ?>', '_blank')}, 5000)"> This is a link </a>
```

**Note**: Browsers do not encourage such behavior as opening new tabs on timer is how popups work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and code, but I don't understand much about that :). Is there any solution to add some code to my code that I posted and to work with a delay? I need this code because it uses a lot of "echo" commands that I need on my template.

Comment: Idk. See if that works:
<a href="#" onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.open('<?php echo clpr_get_coupon_out_url( $post ); ?>', '_blank')}, 5000)" id="coupon-link-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="coupon-code-link" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Click to open site', APP_TD ); ?>" target="_blank" data-clipboard-text="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Show Coupon Code', APP_TD ); ?>" data-tooltip data-click-open="false" data-position="right" data-alignment="center"><span><?php _e( 'Show Coupon Code', APP_TD ); ?></span><i class="fa fa-scissors" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

Comment: No, and now only open the home page because of this <a href="#" ... And no delay. Thanks for try ;) .. I will try to find these commands on javascript somewhere.

Comment: maybe the data-click-open="false" and other data-* things are messing with the onclick event. Try removing those and see what happens